# Swift - animating ImageView

Tags: swift, image, jquery-animate, transform

just a quick issue I'm having regarding animating a moving background image view for my current application setup. Essentially I want to have my currently still background image view scroll up to start position endlessly; but I'm struggling piecing it all together. Can someone help me?

```
 class Flash: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var arrowImage: UIImageView!

    var arrow1: UIImage!
    var arrow2: UIImage!
    var arrow3: UIImage!
    var images: [UIImage]!
    var animatedImage: UIImage!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        toggleFlash()
        arrow1 = UIImage(named: "Arrow1.png")
        arrow2 = UIImage(named: "Arrow2.png")
        arrow3 = UIImage(named: "Arrow3.png")
        images = [arrow1, arrow2, arrow3]
       animatedImage = UIImage.animatedImage(with: images, duration: 1.0)
        arrowImage.image = animatedImage

    }

    func blinkScreen(){

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .curveLinear], animations: {

    }) { _ in
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what you mean by "Essentially I want to have my currently still background image view scroll up to start position endlessly". The code you provided will move the image view 10 pts up over an enormous amount of time meaning that the image view will effectively stand still.

Comment: Lets say I have an image view with four arrows thats all pointing up and I want my image view to stand still but animate it up the top of my View  and back to start position and repeat the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I understand what sort of thing you are going for.

First of all, the duration argument is the duration of each iteration of the animation. Secondly, UIView.animate(...) does not repeat the animation unless you add the .repeat option to the options argument.

So to achieve something closer to what you want, update your code to:

```
func blinkScreen()
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .curveLinear], animations: {
        self.imageV.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -10)
    }) { _ in
        self.imageV.transform = .identity
    }
}
```

And if you want to animate the movement both up and down use the .autoreverse option (and maybe .curveEaseInOut):

```
func blinkScreen()
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse, .curveEaseInOut], animations: {
        self.imageV.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -10)
    }) { _ in
        self.imageV.transform = .identity
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that animation works but right now I have a view controller with a single Image view. I want my image view contain an array of images with same background on it. But when the animation start I want my image to be replaced by a new one and the old disappear with curveLinear.  I have updated my old code with new.